# How to deploy React and Node.js on cPanel

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, cpanel, web-deployment

I am asking here because I have no idea what to do anymore. I want to deploy my React app that uses Nodejs as a server and I cannot find a proper article or forum to help me. They all only talk about how to setup Nodejs or how to setup React. Nothing on how to setup both at the same time. This is my first React project with Nodejs.

I am trying to deploy my React app using a Node.js as a server onto cPanel on my domain. When adding my React `build` folder to `public_html` then the front end is good and obviously Node is not working when I try to use the backend functionalities. When I go and setup a Node.js App in my cPanel I cannot get the js script to point to `server/index.js`, it only selects `index.js` in the root. Check image below:

[image]

I point my `index.js` with my server config to `server/index.js` in my Application startup file but it keeps going to the `index.js` in the app, not `server/index.js`.

My directory is as follows:

```
-app
  -build
  -node_modules
  -public
  -server
     -index.js (must use this one)
  -src
  -.env
  -package.json
  -index.js (keeps using this one)
```

How can I deploy my React app with Node server using cPanel? Please help.

Comment: Can you verify the `.htacces`?

Comment: @SushantPaudel I managed to solve the issue by changing script in package.json and I got an .htaccess in my public_html. But when I run the JS SCRIPT in cPanel I break it. I am not sure which script to run to get the client and server to run simultaneously. On my Localhost client and server runs simultaneously when I run "npm run dev". On cPanel I don't know how to run the React build in public_html and the Nodejs app simultaneously.